# Press any key to boot from USB not working

Tags: windows-7, bootmgr

I am getting an error from a notebook that BOOTMGR is corrupted so I tried to boot from a USB image with Windows 7 to repair the boot. When the Notebook asks me to press any key it's like the keyboard is dead. Nothing happens. I tried also with external keyboard but it still failing. Any ideas?

Comment: Laptop model? (Perhaps it's a known issue.)

Comment: ViewSonic VNB120

Comment: Have you tried booting from a disk?

Comment: BOOTMGR error occured from hard disk. External usb-cdrom is not working also. I read about USB legacy support that should be enabled (from forums etc) and in BIOS there is no option for that